# swapping using the index of an element

Tags: python, indexing

When I was watching videos about introduction to lists for Python I encountered this code:

```py
b = ["banana", "apple", "Microsoft"]
print(b)
```

(when i print this)

```
'banana','apple','Microsoft'
```

I was told to swap the first element and the third element using their index. The working solution that they gave me was this:

```py
b[0], b[2] = b[2], b[0]
print(b)
```

(when i print this):

```
'Microsoft','apple','banana'
```

which was correct. However, I don't understand how the code works, so can anyone please explain?

Comment: It is a tuple assignment. On the right hand side, you have a tuple and you unpack it and assign to the variables on the left.

Comment: `b[0], b[2] = b[2], b[0]` is same as `some_variable = b[2]; b[2] = b[0]; b[0] = some_variable`

Answer (score 0):

In most other languages, you would need to create a temporary variable and then switch them over. In Python, this would look like:

```
a = 1
b = 2

temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

Python allows you to swap these in one line.

```
a = 1
b = 2

a, b = b, a
```

Now, b = 1 and a = 2

The [brackets] at the end of the variable references the position within the list.